# Sorting Alphbetically using Collections.sort

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a Map like this:

```
Map<Account, List<BrandAccount>> accountBrandMap = new HashMap<Account, List<BrandAccount>>();
```

Now I have to sort this map alphabetically based on first name from Key. This is the code I have used:

```
List<Entry<Account, List<BrandAccount>>> entries = new ArrayList<Entry<Account, List<BrandAccount>>>(accountBrandMap.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Entry<Account, List<BrandAccount>>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<Account, List<BrandAccount>> o1,
                    Entry<Account, List<BrandAccount>> o2) {
                String fname1 ="", fname2="";
                        fname1 = !isNull(o1.getKey().getFirst_name()) ? o1
                                .getKey().getFirst_name() : o1
                                .getKey()
                                .getEmail_address()
                                .substring(
                                        0,
                                        o1.getKey().getEmail_address()
                                                .indexOf("@"));

                        fname2 = !isNull(o2.getKey().getFirst_name()) ? o2
                                .getKey().getFirst_name() : o2
                                .getKey()
                                .getEmail_address()
                                .substring(
                                        0,
                                        o2.getKey().getEmail_address()
                                                .indexOf("@"));
                return fname1.compareTo(fname2);
            }
        });

        Map<Account, List<BrandAccount>> orderedMap = new LinkedHashMap<Account, List<BrandAccount>>();
        for (Entry<Account, List<BrandAccount>> entry : entries) {
            orderedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
model.addAttribute("listvar", orderedMap);
```

The problem is that I get a sorted key map but it is not just one sorted map. while printing it gives me two sorted data like this:

{Anna, Belle, Elsa, Sandra,}{ Ariel, Tisca}

It is like two sorted lists in one. I dont know why am I getting it like this.

I'm displaying the output like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${listvar}" var="Listvar">
        <li class="accordion" id="rows${Listvar.key.account_id }">
            <a href='#' class="group-li"><span>${Listvar.key.first_name} ${Listvar.key.last_name}</span> </a>
            <ul class="" style="display: none; margin-top: 15px;">      
                <c:forEach items="${Listvar.value}" var="brandVal">
                    <li>
                        <a href=''>${brandVal.brand.company_name}</a>
                    </li>
                </c:forEach>
            </ul> 
        </li>                               
</c:forEach>
```

This is how it looks like:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h83v223ims18q15/users.png?dl=0

Please Help.
Thanks.

Comment: What/how are you printing? The output does not look like a Map structure...

Comment: @HenningKoehler Please check question I edited it.

Comment: Don't see exactly what's wrong, but I'd suspect that the problem lies in the display, not the sort routine. Are the names (Anna, Belle, ...) all the first-names of accounts?

Comment: Yes these are the first names. I'm sorting as per first names and displaying first name as well last name.

Comment: I'd say check your names very carefully. They may start with invisible characters (e.g. a space) which affect the sort order. If you can't see it, I'd start testing by iterating over the list and checking that names are in order (not as you see it, but as String.compareTo sees it).

Comment: I would suggest you to use TreeMap instead. Just implement `Comparable` interface for `Account` class. Your code would be cleaner that way.

Comment: I got to know the reason why it is giving data in that way: the Names that begin with Capital Letters appear on the first sorted part and the Names that begin with Small letters appear on the second sorted part. So I tried using **.compareToIgnoreCase** but still it didn't work.

Comment: @Enigo I implemented it using TreeMap and Comparator now.

Comment: @User14141111 nice) does everything work fine now?

Comment: Finally it worked using **.compareToIgnoreCase**. I used a class implementing that comparator and I forgot to change .compareToIgnoreCase in that class implementation. Thanks @HenningKoehler and Enigo